# Nontransparent headline in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, transparency

I have an arbitray frame with a **headline** that contains section names, small dots representing sections etc. Anyway, a standard Beamer headline that automatically on top of each frame.

Next, I use:

```
\begin{frame}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure_name.eps}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

However, the figure is big and I would like to take a closer look at some of its sections. To do that, I use:

```
\begin{frame}

    \begin{textblock*}{24cm}(0.45cm,-7.55cm)
    \includegraphics[width=24cm, height=17cm]{figure-name.eps}
    end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
```

When I zoom into the lower part of the figure, the Beamer simply shows only that part of the figure and crops the rest at the boundaries of the frame.

HOWEVER! The part of the figure being cropped on top of the frame COVERS the headline. I want my headline to cover the figure, i.e. for the figure to be hedint the headline, not on top of it.

Comment: Could you show some code which explains what theme do you use and how do you insert the logo on top of it?

Comment: It will probably remain a bad frame in any case, whether you cut off your figure or cut off the headline....

Comment: Hello, sorry for short explanation - I am using Darmstadt theme. I gave a logo as trivial example, it's a bit more technical in practice but the idea is the same - the object I add will overlap with the headline. Can I do something like: "\setbeamertemplate{headline}" and then somehow edit transparency or opaquity?

Comment: How do you insert this overlapping object? Where do you insert it: title, frame contents? Is it the same for all frames? ...

Comment: I insert a text block in a several "standard" frames, as a content, yes. So I begin a frame as: \begin{frame} ...TEXT BLOCK ....\end{frame}. The position of text block is such that it may overlay with the headline - in that case I want headline to cover the text block, not the other way around (thanks for patience!)

Comment: Would you mind to insert this frame in your question? Start with `documentclass` and finish it with `\end{document}`. I still don't understand how a regular text block overlaps headline.

Comment: I added extended explanation in the original post, I hope it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to modify the order of layers beamer uses to build a frame, simply clip the part of the image you don't want to show:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
  \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0.0cm,-2.5cm)
   \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 5cm},clip]{example-image}
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]